# VS Code Snippets - How to Add List of Files to Choice Variable

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

I have a snippet that imports a library that I use often.
I would like to add a choice variable based on the files in the library.
So in the example below ${1:Package} would fill with all the files in the Package Path.

Is this possible?

Current Snippet

```
"Import MyPython Package": {
  "prefix": "MyPython",
  "body": [
    "import sys",
    "# insert at 1, 0 is the script path (or '' in REPL)",
    "sys.path.insert(1, 'Path to Package')",
    "",
    "import ${1:Package}"
  ],
  "description": "Import MyPython Package"
}
```

Goal Snippet

```
"Import MyPython Package": {
  "prefix": "MyPython",
  "body": [
    "import sys",
    "# insert at 1, 0 is the script path (or '' in REPL)",
    "sys.path.insert(1, 'Path to Package')",
    "",
    "import ${1|Package1, Package2, Package3}"
  ],
  "description": "Import MyPython Package"
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more? Im not quite sure what you mean by choice variable.

Comment: A choice variable allows you to choose from a list after you import the snippet.
This snippet variable ${3|w,a|} allows the user to choose "w" or "a". I would like the snippet to read all the files in a folder so they can be used as choices.

I added an example of what it could look like to the question.

Comment: write a `CompletionProvider` in an extension and construct the snippet on the fly and insert it

Comment: how often does the library change, just hard code the choices

Comment: I'll look into the CompletionProvider.
The library does not often enough that hard coding it is out of question, I was just curious if there was a better way to do it as I just started leveraging snippets.